# Is Isotope sorting supports paginated data?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, jquery-isotope

I am amazed with [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and it's sorting capability. But observing most other layouts utilized Isotope, I came to an end that, there's no pagination in any of there. So, I'm wondering, is Isotope support paginated data?

Suppose I've data and their counts:

- Web Design (200)
- Web Development (190)
- Apps Dev (5)

And a total count of data is 300 in a mixture of combinations. Without pagination the page's load time will overflow. And with pagination of 10 items per page...

What would happen then?

With a click on "Web Design" link will it sort 10 data from Web Design category (+with a pagination of 20 pages (20x10=200)), or for example 3 data only from the paginated items of that page (where 7 others are of the other two cat's - WDes 3, WDev 6, Apps 1 (+with the pagination intact - 30 pages))?

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why you wont see a lot of paginatiors in combinations with isotope is because of the filtering.

By default the filtering works like this:

```
$container.isotope({ filter: '.selector' });
```

as you can probably guess it checks the whole DOM and filters out elements that do not have this class set.

On the contrary you can use a anonymous function and alter that behavior like so:

```
$container.isotope({
  filter: function() {
   // do whatever
  }
});
```

Now there are quite a few ways to achieve pagination but in combination with isotope I'd recommend a ajax based approach with a combination off Isotopes Methods you can find [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html).

Rather then having a completed DOM from the start you'll want to add your paginated items dynamically and/or removable.

Wherever you want to add those items in your filter anonymous function or trough your pagination ajax call is up to you I'd probably do it in the function though.